# How to upgrade a jailbreak iOS without loosing Cydia applications?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

How to upgrade a jailbreak iOS without loosing Cydia applications?

Are there any additional steps required in order to keep you configuration and applications between iOS upgrades?

1. itunes backup
2. itunes upgrade
3. jaibreak (probably using redsnow)
4. restore backup using itunes

Answer (score 2):

You can use AptBackup or PkgBackup to backup your Cydia downloads before restoring, then reinstall after the restore and run again to reinstall all the Cydia stuff that you had.

Comment: Since there is always the step of a non-jailbroken upgrade, I don't think there will ever be any method other than what you've described. Which is why I won't upgrade unless I really, really, really must have a feature in the new iOS that isn't already done via the jailbreak.

Comment: That has **never** worked out any good for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can back up and restore your Cydia package selections as follows:

Backup installed package list on current machine

```
dpkg --get-selections > selections.txt
```

Move `selections.txt` to the new machine.

Set package list on new machine and install packages.

```
dpkg --set-selections < selections.txt
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Source: [farslayer's post on LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/%5Baptitude%5D-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-installed-packages-458119/)